# How can this re-usable AngularJS service update on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I developed a re-usable AngularJS service that allows the user to start, stop, and re-set a countdown timer from a view by clicking on buttons in the view.  The re-usable service can be accessed through any controller that includes it.  The working code for the minimal example countdown app can be viewed  [by clicking the link to this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7kzVrDGH0A0eQAQdsyum?p=preview).

But I want the timer to be re-set to its max default value every time a user moves the mouse anywhere in the browser window.  This means adding `$window.addEventListener(...)` somewhere in the service because the service has to be re-usable across any controller, while also responding to any movement of the mouse anywhere over the browser window, even the areas not contained within an HTML element linked to a controller.  Thus, I cannot simply resort to adding `ng-mousemove="somemethod()"` in the html `body` tag [the way this other example does](http://jsfiddle.net/AfNH9/4/).  I would also prefer to avoid [the `$rootScope.broadcast` approach taken by this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382927/listen-to-window-events-in-an-angularjs-service) because I would like to keep the code isolated in the service as much as possible.

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the timer will be re-set to its default value any time the user moves the mouse anywhere in the browser window?**

Though [all of the code is in the plnkr for easy editing](http://plnkr.co/edit/7kzVrDGH0A0eQAQdsyum?p=preview), I am also including it here.

`index.html` is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Timer</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="myTimer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="exampleController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="intervalExample">

<div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Test variable: {{ mytimer.testvariable }}<br>

    Time Remaining : <font color='red'>{{mytimer.timeleft}}</font>
    <br>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="mytimer.startCountdown()">Start Countdown</button>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="mytimer.stopCountdown()">Stop Countdown</button>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="mytimer.resetCountdown()">Reset Timer</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js` is:

```
angular.('intervalExample',['ExampleController']);
```

`exampleController.js` is:

```
angular
.module('ExampleController', ['mytimer'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'mytimer', function($scope, mytimer) {

    $scope.mytimer = mytimer;
}]);
```

`myTimer.js` is:

```
angular
.module('mytimer', [])
.service('mytimer', ['$rootScope', '$interval', function($rootScope, $interval) {

    var $this = this;
    this.testvariable = "some value. ";

        this.timeleft = 15;

        var stop;
        this.startCountdown = function() {
          // Don't start a new countdown if we are already counting down
          if ( angular.isDefined(stop) ) return;

          stop = $interval(function() {
            if ($this.timeleft > 0 ) {
              $this.timeleft = $this.timeleft - 1;
            } else {
              $this.stopCountdown();
            }
         }, 1000);
        };

        this.stopCountdown = function() {
          if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
            $interval.cancel(stop);
            stop = undefined;
          }
        };

        this.resetCountdown = function() {
          this.timeleft = 15;
        };

//        this.$on('$destroy', function() {
            // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
//            $this.stopCountdown();
//        });

          function subsFunc() {
            $window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            $this.timeleft = 15;
        })
  }

}]);
```

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for a directive to do the start/stops. Why do all that controller injection and repeated code? Same for timer display...use a directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues to consider:

1. You are never calling `subsFunc()` and when you do will see that
   `$window` is not injected in service
2. You will need to [**debounce**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/can-someone-explain-the-debounce-function-in-javascript) the mousemove callback since the event
   triggers about every pixel. Resetting your timer every pixel makes no
   sense and would cause significant  needless digests.
3. Use of directive for  buttons would negate needing to inject in numerous controllers
4. Same for timer display ... can be directive and depending on UI combined with buttons

Comment: Well really not clear what you are looking for then. You know the function needs to be called already to do the reset

Comment: It will if you inject `$window` and call the function ... but that gets down to issue of needing debounce also. Add a debounce to it ...lots of available code all over the web for doing it.

Comment: simply put `subsFunc();` in service. Remember that services are singletons so will activate once per whole page load

Comment: So did you try it @CodeMed? Works fine fixing injection and calling the function. But is heavy on digests without debounce