# $window.addEventListener not triggered in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to refresh an angular table when a message arrives informing new data is ready; I am trying to use this code following the hint at:
[Listen to window events in an Angularjs service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382927/listen-to-window-events-in-an-angularjs-service/28383448),
but the event is not even received when command:

```
 parent.postMessage("printComments", "*");
```

is sent by another page in a frame.

What is the business?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myapp">
        <table ng-table="commentsTable">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in obj.data track by $index">
                <td class="plantCell">{{item.nome}}: </td>
            <td class="statusCell">{{item.status}}</td>
            <td class="statusCell">{{item.testo}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <script language="javascript">
            var app=angular.module('myapp', []);
            var printOperation;
            function GetFromLocalStorage(key) {
                var items=localStorage.getItem(key);
                console.log(items);
                if (items===null){
                    console.log("item null");
                    return null;
                } else {
                if (typeof items!= "string") {items = JSON.stringify(items);}
                    return items;
                }
            }
            app.service('servicename', function($window, $rootScope) {
                function subsFunc() {
                        $window.addEventListener('printComments',
                            function(e) {
                                alert("arriva evento");
                                $rootScope.$broadcast('app.clickEvent', e);
                             });
                    }
                    return {
                            "subscribeMe": subsFunc
                    }
            });
            app.controller('MyCtrl',
                function($scope,servicename) {
                    $scope.data = {};
                        $scope.printComments = function() {
                //$scope.obj=GetFromLocalStorage("AllComments");
                            $scope.data.obj = [{
                            "nome": "first",
                            "status": 1,
                            "testo": "Rottura rullo 1!!!"
                            }, {
                            "nome": "second",
                            "status": 0,
                            "testo": "Rottura rullo fsdfsf!!!"
                            }];
                            console.log("ricevo evento e ricarico tabella");
                            console.log($scope.data.obj);

                        }
                        servicename.subscribeMe();
                        $scope.$on('app.clickEvent', function(a, b) {
                            console.log("evento");
                            alert("on received");
                            $scope.printComments();
                    });
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is your controller? you need to define the controller in the js

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []); 
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.obj = [{nome:"Sss"}]
})
var printOperation;

function GetFromLocalStorage(key) {
    var items = localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log(items);
    if (items === null) {
        console.log("item null");
        return null;
    } else {
        if (typeof items != "string") {
            items = JSON.stringify(items);
        }
        return items;
    }
}
app.service('serviceName', function($window, $rootScope) {
    function subsFunc() {
        $rootScope.printComments = function() {
            //$rootScope.obj=GetFromLocalStorage("AllComments");
            $rootScope.obj = [{
                "nome": "first",
                "status": 1,
                "testo": "Rottura rullo 1!!!"
            }, {
                "nome": "second",
                "status": 0,
                "testo": "Rottura rullo fsdfsf!!!"
            }];
            console.log("ricevo evento e ricarico tabella");
            console.log($rootScope.obj);

        }

        $window.addEventListener('printComments',
            function(e) {
                console.log("ricevo evento");
                $rootScope.printComments();
            })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table ng-table="commentsTable">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in obj track by $index">
                <td class="plantCell">{{item.nome}}: </td>
            <td class="statusCell">{{item.status}}</td>
            <td class="statusCell">{{item.testo}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You had some error in you code. I fixed it look at the snippet. there is no event **printComments** in $window object so i changed it to **load** for demo purpose, you could change it according to your need.

You forgot to inject the service in your controller, so your event listener was not registered.this line:

> servicename.subscribeMe();

```js
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
  console.log('parent received message!:  ',e.data);
  $(window).trigger(e.data);
},false);

  var app=angular.module('myapp', []);
  var printOperation;
  function GetFromLocalStorage(key) {
    var items=localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log(items);
    if (items===null){
      console.log("item null");
      return null;
    } else {
      if (typeof items!= "string") {items = JSON.stringify(items);}
      return items;
    }
  }
  app.service('servicename', function($window, $rootScope) {
    function subsFunc() {
      //$($window).on("printComments", function(e){
      $($window).on("printComments",
        function(e) {
          alert("arriva evento");
          $rootScope.$broadcast('app.clickEvent', e);
        });
    }
    return {
      "subscribeMe": subsFunc
    };
  });
  app.controller('MyCtrl',
    function($scope,servicename,$timeout) {
      $scope.data = {};
      $scope.printComments = function() {
                //$scope.obj=GetFromLocalStorage("AllComments");
                $scope.data.obj = [{
                  "nome": "first",
                  "status": 1,
                  "testo": "Rottura rullo 1!!!"
                }, {
                  "nome": "second",
                  "status": 0,
                  "testo": "Rottura rullo fsdfsf!!!"
                }];
                console.log("ricevo evento e ricarico tabella");
                console.log($scope.data.obj);

              };
              servicename.subscribeMe();
              $scope.$on('app.clickEvent', function(a, b) {
                console.log("evento");
                alert("on received");
                $timeout(function(){
                   $scope.printComments();
                });
               
              });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myapp">
  <table servicename>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data.obj track by $index">
      <td class="plantCell">{{item.nome}}: </td>
      <td class="statusCell">{{item.status}}</td>
      <td class="statusCell">{{item.testo}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<iframe src="//sample ifream with postmessage script"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I am changing the sample and title.

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci sure, if the problem is different i would try to find the solution.

Comment: Please check the updated code from the linked solution.

Comment: I tested your code and in fact the alerts is displayed, yet when I substitute it with my own even been trigggered by another panel 'printComments' nothing happens. I am also updating my code.

Comment: Moreovoer, even using 'load', the table is not updated anyway.

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci check now